How to capture the Crash tae and Crash logs of Salesforce iOS Mobile publisher app?
Our users have been reporting that they are facing ios app crash issues very often. We wanted to get the crash rate of our app as well as the Crash logs. When reached out to support they redirceting us to Apple which is a paid service. Anyone here please let me know how you guys are handling it.
Thanks,
Bency

Are all/majority of your users facing Salesforce Mobile App crashing? If yes, are their Salesforce Mobile App updated to the latest version? and what does crash here means; is it app automatically closing?

Not all, few of our users are facing issue. While using the app white screen appears randomly throughout the day.  Only way to move forward is to restart phone.  User clears cache daily.
